# Conversion of LST from K to F in gee

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to get LST using Landsat 8. I have successfully generated images for LST in Kelvin. But I need to get images in Fahrenheit. I'm trying to use expression for formula but I don't know How I can write K in formula or what to do so that I can get in F. It will be great if there is other way to get in F. I'm sharing code where you can clearly the expression.

```
//var satellite = 'L8';
//var date_start = '2022-06-01';
//var date_end = '2022-08-30';
//var use_ndvi = true;
var images_lst = function(image){
var F = image.multiply((1.8(K - 273)) + 32)// from K to F 
return F;
}
//var LandsatColl = LandsatLST.collection(satellite, date_start, date_end, geometry, use_ndvi)
.map(images_lst)
//print(LandsatColl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as expected modifying your function as follows:

```
var images_lst = function(image){
  var F = ee.Image(image).subtract(273).multiply(1.8).add(32)// from K to F 
  return F.set('system:time_start', ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')));
}
```

and mapping LandsatColl again just before the TimeSeries chart:

```
LandsatColl = LandsatColl.map(images_lst);

var TimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.series(
    LandsatColl, geometry, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30, 'system:time_start')
        .setChartType('ScatterChart')
        .setOptions({
          vAxis: {title: bandname},
          lineWidth: 1,
          pointSize: 4
});
```

Complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c6ea87bf49b6cf014d47f240160261b1?noload=1).

After running it in GEE code editor, in following picture was printed the chart with values expressed in Fahrenheit degrees.

[image]